# How to get author name and last updated date of documents?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I get author name and last updated date of the documents uploaded in Marklogic Server ?

Comment: Are you referring to the a MarkLogic database doc update date / MarkLogic security user name, or are you referring to the metadata from a source file or source system such as the metadata inside a Microsoft Word file?  Please be more specific with your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've turned off the maintenance of the last-modified property, you can find it on the document's property fragment (you can browse these via Explore mode in query console).

In the future, last-modified maintenance may be off by default, fyi.

I'm not aware of any notion of user account associated with the last modification that is maintained.  You'd need to add and maintain that metadata yourself via a trigger or CPF or some other mechanism.